# Reliability of HTTP HEAD method

Tags: http

I'm trying to automate detection of broken links and I was startled to see that HTTP [HEAD method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEAD_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods) is not always reliable. For example the URL: http://www.youtube.com/mit -- the URL is accessible with GET method but trying to contact the URL with HEAD method ends up with receiving 404 error (not found).

**Note:** The example can be easily checked online via: http://web-sniffer.net/ 
(I'm not affiliated with the webpage in any way)

So how reliable is the HEAD method in the end?

---

As a reasonable solution I see just don't use HEAD and always use GET method always but it is wastes bandwidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HEAD` is required to work as described in [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.4); however, its implementation is always at the mercy of the developers of any specific site, and it is not possible to enforce RFC-compliance. You could be fairly confident that any site is likely to support `HEAD` reasonably well, but as you have already discovered, there are no guarantees.