# How to interrupt WebRequest (GET) after a specified amount of data?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

As I find out the HTTP HEAD method is not always reliable in practice: [Reliability of HTTP HEAD method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088796/reliability-of-http-head-method)

Is it possible to emulate the HTTP HEAD method with the HTTP GET method? I mean I just need headers of the answer so it should suffice to restrict maximum amount of data. Can I do that in .NET?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to emulate the HTTP HEAD method with the HTTP GET method?

No, of course not. A GET request always comes with a body in response. That's what the HTTP specification says. So unless you find a web server which violates the HTTP specification I don't think it will work. Only the HEAD verb is designed to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but the response is downloaded via TCP/IP. So I should be able to interrupt the connection in case I have enough data, right?

Comment: No, because the web server will have already written the response to the network socket unless of course the server uses chunked transfer encoding, but even in this case it would have written some chunks. You could of course interrupt the reading (if you use a TcpListener and go down the TCP/IP level), but you will already have wasted the bandwidth, which I thought is what you initially wanted to avoid.

Comment: I want to save bandwidth but on the other hand it doesn't have to be 100 per cent efficient. It is a question of measure. Thank you for your answer and the comment!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5354384/99256 -- the last comment is probably what I'm looking for (simply make a GET request and terminate connection if the content-type is not what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebClient.OpenRead()` which returns a stream.  Read in the required number of bytes and then close the stream.

Comment: The fact that you have read only a required number of bytes from the stream doesn't mean at all that the server hasn't already written all the response body to the network socket, wasting all the bandwidth which is what the OP wants to avoid in the first place.